# How to delete from a multidimensional array if addon_id key is not present

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have figured out all of the issues I had with this on my own up until here. So far I got this to work to the point where I am able to save data properly. The only question I have is, how do I remove arrays where addon_id is not present?

I want to remove the last two "addon_price" from an array.

```
[
  {"addon_id":"7","addon_price":"12"},
  {"addon_id":"8","addon_price":"45"},
  {"addon_id":"9","addon_price":"66"},
  {"addon_price":null}, <- remove
  {"addon_price":null} <- remove
]
```

This is my code

```
$p = ItemsAddon::where('item_id', $request->item_id)->pluck('addon_id');
    
   if($request->addon_id) {
    
      $addons = [
        'addon_id' => $request->addon_id,
        'addon_price' => $request->addon_price
      ];
    
    
      $values = [];
      foreach($addons as $key => $addon) {
    
         foreach($addon as $subkey => $subvalue) {
    
             $values[$subkey][$key] = $subvalue;
    
         }
    
      }
    
      foreach($values as $vkey => $value) {
    
      $item_addon = new ItemsAddon;
    
         if(!$p->contains($value['addon_id'])) {
    
            $item_addon->item_id = $request->item_id;
            $item_addon->addon_id =  $value['addon_id'];
            $item_addon->addon_price = $value['addon_price'];
                     
            $item_addon->save();
    
         } else {
                      
            $item_addon->where(
            [
               'item_id' => $request->item_id,
               'addon_id' => $value['addon_id'],
            ])->update([
                 'addon_id' => $value['addon_id'],
                 'addon_price' => $value['addon_price'],
            ]);
    
         }
    
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: Hello jasdev, have you thought of deleting objects that simply do not carry a key?

Comment: Hello Jameu, yes I don't need last two "addon_price" arrays where "addon_id" doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array like this

```
 $a = [
    ["addon_id" => "7", "addon_price" => "12"],
    ["addon_id" => "8", "addon_price" => "45"],
    ["addon_id" => "9", "addon_price" => "66"],
    ["addon_price" => null],
    ["addon_price" => null]
];
```

then you can filter null values in this way:

```
$b = collect($a)->filter(function ($r) {
    return isset($r["addon_id"]);
})->toArray();
```